# Accessing saved data for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension. Specifically I am trying to make button to save data then another button that when pressed will open a new tab with the web address that the user previously saved. I believe I have the button to save the data working but I am not sure how to access the data once it is save.

Here is the code for both the save button and the button which takes the user to the website previously saved.

```
document.getElementById("save").onclick = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById("userWebsite").value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "data" : d }, function() {
           if (chrome.runtime.error) {
                  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("Runtime error.");
           }
    });
    window.close();
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("Save worked");
}

document.getElementById("goToSavedWeb").onclick=function()
{
  chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(value) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ website: value, message:"Go_To_Clicked"});
}
```

I get the error expected string but got object for the property url. I was wondering how exactly to solve this error? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving a JavaScript object with `data` property, so in order to get it you need to access his property:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ website: value.data, message:"Go_To_Clicked"});
```